# Traducción de Flashbulb memory

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

En inglés un Flashbulb memory es un recuerdo muy vivido de un acontecimiento de gran importancia histórica o emocional, que queda grabado en la memoria de las personas que lo viven como si fuera una instantánea fotográfica. Son hechos de los que todo el mundo recuerda dónde se encontraba en el momento, como por ejemplo, el aterrizaje del hombre en la luna, el asesinato de JFK, o los atentados del 11-S.
¿Cómo podría traducirse al español? Se me ocurre por ejemplo recuerdo imborrable, pero es demasiado general y no transmite el sentido de colectivo, que afecta a todas las personas que lo viven.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Aunque no signifique exactamente lo mismo, se me ocurre "acontecimiento histórico".

Comment: No es lo mismo. Por ejemplo, en España estoy seguro de que todo el mundo recuerda dónde se encontraba cuando ganó la final de la copa del mundo de fútbol, y sin embargo no creo que eso se pueda considerar un acontecimiento histórico.

Comment: Coincido contigo en que acontecimiento histórico no es adecuado como traducción. Otra cosa es el ejemplo que pones que sí es un acontecimiento histórico, independientemente de la relevancia subjetiva que pueda tener para ti o para mí. Como noticia sorprendente y de alcance emocional para muchos, además puede originar una "flashbulb memory" de esas.

Answer (score 3):

La manera en la que yo aludiría a un

> **flashbulb memory**

es la de

> un recuerdo o **memoria grabada a fuego** (que la torna *inolvidable*)

Creo que las características salientes de una **flashbulb memory** se implican  con esa expresión en castellano:

- la vivacidad con que se registró el hecho
- el impacto sobre uno, por el carácter conmocionante de la experiencia
- la conciencia de las circunstancias aledañas, o el detalle del contexto que queda asociado en forma inseparable
- la remembranza que asegura la fijación de por vida en nuestra memoria como algo trascendente e imborrable

Comment: El uso de flashbulb evoca la idea de dejar la impresión grabada, así como un fogonazo de luz nos deja una mancha luminosa en la vista durante un tiempo. Por tanto la idea de grabar a fuego no sólo refuerza la idea de memoria imposible de olvidar, sino que también establece el paralelismo de acción que produce una marca física. Me parece la mejor opción como traducción.

Comment: Exacto. Las traducciones no tienen por qué ser calcos del otro idioma, hay unas sugestiones que van implícitas con otros términos que funcionalmente representan mejor esas ideas

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que he podido averiguar en [una breve investigación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashbulb_memory), el témino **flashbulb memory** fue acuñado en 1977 por R.Brown y J.Kulik en [su artículo](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/001002777790018X?via%3Dihub) homónimo "Flashbulb memories"; es decir, es un término recientemente inventado y dirigido a una audiencia especializada. No aparece recogido en diccionarios como el Oxford o el Cambridge asociado a la palabra **flashbulb**.

No parece que sea un término común en el habla inglesa. Difícilmente podemos encontrar equivalente en el habla común española.

He encontrado este [artículo](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/111777.pdf) de 1993 de José María Ruiz-Vargas de la Universidad Autónoma de Madrid, donde se referencia el de Brown y Kulik. En él se traduce el término como **recuerdos-destello**.

Por otro lado, en este [otro artículo](https://www.redalyc.org/jatsRepo/4596/459653862011/html/index.html) de los investigadores colombianos Tamayo-Agudelo, Chaves Castaño y Cárdenas, se mantiene la palabra inglesa flashbulb directamente, hacíendose referencia a los **recuerdos flashbulb**.

Dado que el término **[memorias flash](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoria_flash)**, quizás el más cercano a su original inglés, designa ya una cosa completamente distinta, podrías asumir la traducción de Ruiz-Vargas, pero siempre haciendo referencia al término científico inglés para que puedan entenderlo psicólogos y otros especialista de esa índole.